# Postman : socket hang up and how we fix segmentation fault in Laravel v10?

Tags: postman, laravel-10

Inside postman
GET http://localhost/api/orders/6
Error: socket hang up
Request Headers
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.31.3
Postman-Token: 073b75fd-0dd1-4ecf-875c-9e4e9a83b597
Host: localhost
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive

While running code getting error in postman and Laravel.
php artisan route:list
Segmentation fault

Tried this steps

Deleting vendor folder and composer install

composer dump-autoload

composer update

./artisan cache:clear

Comment: "Segmentation fault" usually happens if the PHP extortions are not properly installed or unsupported versions, try deleting vendor folder itself and do a composer install.
Do check you are on latest PHP version compatible with your laravel version

Comment: Already deleted vendor file and did composer install.

Comment: could you paste your php ini and laravel version in the question

Comment: Issue is resolved by correcting code.